# Can I grab the minecraft server save files directly from the server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For example, my friend, x has a awesome server map. I want to play it offline on my computer, but I can't seem to find any way to get the save files and then play it offline. 

So, is there any way for me to get access to the server's save files and then playing it offline?

**EDIT**

it's online, in a remote place in which i have no access to and i can only access the server thru minecraft